# Parsing GPX files with SAX parser or XmlPullParser

Tags: android, gpx

I have a number of gpx files that my app creates and will need to parse at a later stage in the app. 
I'm having trouble parsing them in general. I've seen alot of examples of parsers on this site and others but they all use objects like `Tracks`and `TrakcPoints` but what these classes contain can't be found. I would really like just to be able to parse the file and sort it into an `ArrayList` of `Location`. I will need to get the long and lat from the file as well as the time and elevation.

Can some one help me with this problem? 
I don't mind if use `SAX parser` or an `Xml pull parser`or another method of doing it.

Comment: A gpx file has zero,one or more tracks, routes or waypoints so it makes sense that gpx parsers have those type of objects. Gpx does not have anyhing called 'location'. You can look at the specs at: http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/ Are your files valid gpx at all or is it your own xml format?

Comment: In location i'm taking about android.location which actually has most of the attributes that is in the gpx files long, lat, time, elevation, time etc. [Android Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, might not be the most elegant way of doing it but it works

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.location.Location;


public class GpxReader
{
private static final SimpleDateFormat gpxDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

public static List<Location> getPoints(File gpxFile)
{
    List<Location> points = null;
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(gpxFile);
        Document dom = builder.parse(fis);
        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("trkpt");

        points = new ArrayList<Location>();

        for(int j = 0; j < items.getLength(); j++)
        {
            Node item = items.item(j);
            NamedNodeMap attrs = item.getAttributes();
            NodeList props = item.getChildNodes();

            Location pt = new Location("test");

            pt.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(attrs.getNamedItem("lat").getTextContent()));
            pt.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(attrs.getNamedItem("lon").getTextContent()));

            for(int k = 0; k<props.getLength(); k++)
            {
                Node item2 = props.item(k);
                String name = item2.getNodeName();
                if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("time")) continue;
                try
                {
                    pt.setTime((getDateFormatter().parse(item2.getFirstChild().getNodeValue())).getTime());
                }

                catch(ParseException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            for(int y = 0; y<props.getLength(); y++)
            {
                Node item3 = props.item(y);
                String name = item3.getNodeName();
                if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("ele")) continue;
                pt.setAltitude(Double.parseDouble(item3.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()));
            }

            points.add(pt);

        }

        fis.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(ParserConfigurationException ex)
    {

    }

    catch (SAXException ex) {
    }

    return points;
}

public static SimpleDateFormat getDateFormatter()
  {
    return (SimpleDateFormat)gpxDate.clone();
  }

}
```

Hope this helps some people

Answer (score 1):

with SAX:
GpxImportActivity.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class GpxImportActivity extends Activity {
private String fileName ="gpsTrack.gpx";
private File sdCard;
private List<Location> locationList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpx_import);

    locationList = new ArrayList<Location>();

    sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();     
    if (!sdCard.exists() || !sdCard.canRead()) {
        Log.d("GpxImportActivity", "SD-Card not available or not readable");
        finish();
    }
    boolean availableFile = new File(sdCard, fileName).exists();
    if (!availableFile) {
        Log.d("GpxImportActivity", "File \"" +fileName+ "\" not available");
        finish();
    } else {
        Log.d("GpxImportActivity", "File \"" +fileName+ "\" found");
    }

    try {
    System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver","org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
    XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    /*
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    spf.setValidating(false);
    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    */      
    GpxFileContentHandler gpxFileContentHandler = new GpxFileContentHandler();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(gpxFileContentHandler);

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(sdCard,fileName));
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(fileReader);          
    xmlReader.parse(inputSource);

    locationList = gpxFileContentHandler.getLocationList(); 

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gpx_import, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

GpxFileContentHandler.java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.location.Location;

public class GpxFileContentHandler implements ContentHandler {
    private String currentValue;
    private Location location;
    private List<Location> locationList;
    private final SimpleDateFormat GPXTIME_SIMPLEDATEFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    public GpxFileContentHandler() {
        locationList = new ArrayList<Location>();
    }

    public List<Location> getLocationList() {
        return locationList;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("trkpt")) {
            location = new Location("gpxImport");
            location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(atts.getValue("lat").trim()));
            location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(atts.getValue("lon").trim()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("ele")) {
            location.setAltitude(Double.parseDouble(currentValue.trim()));
        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {
            try {
            Date date = GPXTIME_SIMPLEDATEFORMAT.parse(currentValue.trim());
            Long time = date.getTime();
            location.setTime(time);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("trkpt")) {
            locationList.add(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data)
        throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
        public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
            throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ready to use, open source, and fully functional java GpxParser (and much more) here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/geokarambola/

Details here
https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/110606810455751902142

With the above library parsing a GPX file is a one liner:

```
Gpx gpx = GpxFileIo.parseIn( "SomeGeoCollection.gpx" ) ;
```

Getting its points, routes or tracks trivial too:

```
ArrayList<Route> routes = gpx.getRoutes( ) ;
Route route = routes.get(0) ; // First route.
```

Then you can iterate the route's points and get their lat/lon/ele directly

```
for(RoutePoint rtePt: route.getRoutePoints( ))
  Location loc = new Location( rtePt.getLatitude( ), rtePt.getLongitude( ) ) ;
```